# Delete layer before creating a new one with react-leaflet-draw in leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-draw

My purpose here is to allow only one polygon on the map. My approach has been saving the new layer during `onCreated` method in a var or array and in the method `onDrawStart` get it and delete, so once the user tries to draw another shape, the previous one gets removed, but this is not working, any suggestion how to make it possible?

```
onCreated = (e) => {
  coordinates = e.layer._bounds;
  layer.push(e.layer);
}

onDrawStart = (e) => {
  layer.forEach((ele) => {
    ele.remove()
  });
}
```

Is there maybe any way to access to onDelete and to access here to the built in remove all??

Comment: Hi @Jose Clavero! Did you check my answer? Does it answer your question?

Comment: It works great, exactly as I was aiming, thanks a lot @kboul !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by checking the stored drawn layers number using a `featureGroupRef`. If the number is bigger than one then delete the previous stored layer and only keep the latest one. Here is the code:

```
const [editableFG, setEditableFG] = useState(null);

const onCreated = e => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(editableFG);

    // here you have all the stored layers
    const drawnItems = editableFG.leafletElement._layers;
    console.log(drawnItems);
    // if the number of layers is bigger than 1 then delete the first
    if (Object.keys(drawnItems).length > 1) {
        Object.keys(drawnItems).forEach((layerid, index) => {
            if (index > 0) return;
            const layer = drawnItems[layerid];
            editableFG.leafletElement.removeLayer(layer);
        });
        console.log(drawnItems); // here you will get only the last one
    }
};

const onFeatureGroupReady = reactFGref => {
    // store the featureGroup ref for future access to content
    setEditableFG(reactFGref);
};

return (
    <Map
        center={[37.8189, -122.4786]}
        zoom={13}
        style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
        <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <FeatureGroup
            ref={featureGroupRef => {
                onFeatureGroupReady(featureGroupRef);
            }}>
            <EditControl position="topright" onCreated={onCreated} />
        </FeatureGroup>
    </Map>
);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kboul/react-leaflet-draw-only-one-shape?file=/src/Map.jsx)

Comment: Hi there, I used your solution to gain ability to draw only one shape, but I got ```cannot read propery leafletElement of undefined```, I used leaflet v1.7.1, leaflet-draw 1.0.4, react-leaflet v2.8.3 and react-leaflet-draw v0.19.8, I guess leafletElement is replaced with something alternative in new versions. How can I implement deleting shapes when new shape is created in versions above?

Comment: Please ask this in a new question and provide an example with your attempt with preferably a reproducible demo.

Answer (score 0):

kbouls answer does not work anymore with the current react-leaflet since they removed ref access to FeatureGroup.

Proposed solution for the new version:

```
let lastAddedPolygonID;

  const _onCreate = (e) => {

    if (layerType === "polygon") {

      // Remove previous polygon from map
      if (lastAddedPolygonID) {
        e.sourceTarget._layers[lastAddedPolygonID].remove();
      }
      lastAddedPolygonID = _leaflet_id;
    }
  };
```

Not sure if it creates any unexpected side-effects, please edit my answer if it does.